# Система убивает приложение в случайные моменты времени без краша(?)

Tags: android, kill

Я просто пытаюсь понять причину. Наше приложение достаточно стабильно и неплохо оптимизировано, но время от времени оно просто выключается при работe. Пользователь использует его, и тут приложение закрывается без каких-либо крашей или сообщений ANR - так себе опыт. Что мы уже сделали:

- используем UncaughtExceptionHandler и пишем логи на диск для анализа. Журналы пусты, никакой информации о сбоях для этих случаев
- используем Firebase crashlityc - там тоже пусто
- проверяем приложение с помощью prfiler и leakcanary - утечек нет, памяти в среднем расходуем ~ 200 Мб

Несколько слов о нашем приложении:

- clear arhitecture, Kotlin, MVVM, coroutines, dagger, retrofit, room, one single activity app
- приложение должно работать постоянно, бесконечно. Оно представляет собой интерфейс для аппаратного терминала.
- большая часть фрагментов сохраняется в backstack и переиспользуется, это помогает ускорить открытие экрана после первого использования фрагмента. Никаких утечек, никаких дубликатов фрагментов или viewModels нет
- мы используем Glide для загрузки и предварительного просмотра аватаров пользователей. Боюсь, что утечки могут быть частью растровых изображений или jpg. Profiler не показывает этого спустя 1-2 часа тестов, но я не тестировал приложение в течении целой недели непрерывной работы
- возможно перебои в работе приложения происходят чаще, когда устройство не заряжено или только что запущено (первые 10-20 минут после запуска устройства)
- у большинства клиентов плохое подключение к WIFI
- у нас есть ~ 10 модулей, большая часть из них - собственные канвас библиотеки
- прерывния случаются в случайные моменты...
- у нас также есть проблема ANR для некоторых клиентов, мы добавили ANR watchdog, скоро должны узнать причину.
- у нас порядка 50-60 синглетонов. Не уверен, много это или мало, но первоначальный план заключался в максимальном переиспользовании объектов, дабы все работало шустрее

Я думаю, это нативный краш или какая-та утечка - система прибивает приложение. Истинную причину я до сих пор не знаю. Если вы сталкивался с подобной проблемой, пожалуйста, поделитесь своим опытом, возможно он будет нам полезен. Спасибо!

Comment: Linux (именно на этом ядре работает оболочка, называемая android) при серьезной нехватке памяти убивает приложения (эта штука называется [OOM process killer](https://docs.memset.com/other/linux-s-oom-process-killer),  выбирает жертву по неким внутренним критериям)

Comment: да, но 200 мб не так много. Довольно странно убивать приложение, при 2 ГБ свободной памяти. Как бы понять точную причину смерти?

Comment: К сожалению, я не программирую в андроиде. Попоробуйте посмотреть [эти ответы](https://stackoverflow.com/q/624857/7286264) (искал по запросу `android oom killer log`)